# gcloud compute backend-services provides a "not found" error

Tags: gcloud

For some unclear reason the gcloud compute backend-services does not find a resource even it is listed.
I run the command:

```
gcloud compute backend-services list
```

And get the output:

```
NAME                                                     BACKENDS                                                                                     PROTOCOL
k8s1-48550837-defaul-reverse-proxy-captcha-s-8-9edaabba  us-central1-c/networkEndpointGroups/k8s1-48550837-defaul-reverse-proxy-captcha-s-8-9edaabba  HTTP
k8s1-48550837-default-admission-service-80-ccc76f21      us-central1-c/networkEndpointGroups/k8s1-48550837-default-admission-service-80-ccc76f21      HTTP
k8s1-48550837-default-agent-service-80-46302173          us-central1-c/networkEndpointGroups/k8s1-48550837-default-agent-service-80-46302173          HTTP
k8s1-48550837-default-authproxy-service-80-f50b4f37      us-central1-c/networkEndpointGroups/k8s1-48550837-default-authproxy-service-80-f50b4f37      HTTP
```

But for any one of the backends I am trying to get description or edit, I get error.
For example, this command:

```
gcloud compute backend-services describe k8s1-48550837-default-agent-service-80-46302173
```

returns error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.backend-services.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/radware-cto/regions/us-central1/backendServices/k8s1-48550837-default-agent-service-80-46302173' was not found
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `--global` to the `describe` command?

Is compute/project set correctly? (gcloud config set project ...)

Comment: using the --global fixed this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP confirmed --global works in a comment.

The reason this works is because the 'describe' command will by default describe the resource in the default compute/region (gcloud config set compute/region...)

You can see this in your error message:
 `- The resource .../regions/us-central1/backendServices/...`

However, as this resource is global, we need to specify `--global` flag to override the default region.

[Additional information here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/describe)